# Android : disable BroadcastReceiver from other apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I know how to disable broadcast receiver with package Manager on Runtime, but it's only for classes of the same package. Is it possible to enable/disable broadcast receiver from others apps with root privilege? If so, how can we do that?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: refer the answer of this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393356/go-sms-pro-overriding-android-provider-telephony-sms-received,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600266/suppress-block-broastreceiver-in-another-app
 if still confused please ask